# How to put space in a text loop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to give some width or space in "Your Likes" section between the users. How can I put some space, please give some suggestion and example.

```
    children: [
                            UserImageSmall(
                              height: 64,
                              width: 64,
                              url: inactiveMatches[index].matchedUser.imageUrls),
                              Text(
                                inactiveMatches[index].matchedUser.name,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                              ),
                          ],
```

How can I remove the error showed in the "Your Chats" section here I want some help. Please let me know how can I do it. Please check the code and image below.

```
 Text('Your Chats',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5),
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: activeMatches.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return InkWell (
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ChatScreen(userMatch: userMatch,),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Row(children: [
                      UserImageSmall(
                        height: 60,
                        width: 60,
                        url: activeMatches[index].matchedUser.imageUrls,
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              activeMatches[index].matchedUser.name,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(
                              activeMatches[index].chat![0].messages[0].message,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
          )
```

This is the exact emulator screen running with this given code.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

1. In Your Likes section, give width to UserImageSmall Widget such as:

   `Container( width: 16, child: UserImageSmall())`
2. Check index 0 exists or not, as in the image seems like null on index: 0

   `activeMatches[index].chat![0].messages[0].message`

I have modified the code, hope this helps!

```
 Text('Your Chats',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: activeMatches.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return InkWell (
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ChatScreen(userMatch: userMatch,),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Row(children: [
                  UserImageSmall(
                    height: 60,
                    width: 60,
                    url: activeMatches[index].matchedUser.imageUrls,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          activeMatches[index].matchedUser.name,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text(
                          activeMatches[index].chat![0]==null ? ""
                          : activeMatches[index].chat![0].messages[0].message,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
      )
```